# Swift WKWebView issue using Apple Sample Code

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am only just starting to learn Swift.

Following along a tutorial, the AboutViewController is for a view set up to show information of the app.

The tutorial used UIWebView to deal with the html file supplying the content. But the official doc recommends using WKWebView instead.

Right now the view of the AboutViewController consists of a background imageview and a button to dismiss the view.

using Apple Sample Code from the class reference for WKWebView

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class AboutViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self

        view = webView

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        if let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "info", withExtension: "html") {
            if let htmlData = try? Data(contentsOf: filePath) {
                let baseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath)
                webView.load(htmlData,
                             mimeType: "text/html",
                             characterEncodingName: "UTF-8",
                             baseURL: baseURL)
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func close() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Xcode shows the following three errors

- Swift Compiler Error: Expected declaration in declaration of "AboutViewController"
- 'override' can only be specified on class members on the line of didReceiveMemoryWarning()
- Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction

I still haven't figured out why.

Guidance needed, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Swift3. Drop your html file (here test.html) to your project.

```
// If needed disable nabber and grey background
    WebView.scrollView.bounces = false
    WebView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    WebView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test" + langue, withExtension:"html")
    let req = NSURLRequest(url: url!)
    WebView.loadRequest(req as URLRequest)
```